# How to activate a conda environment globally for any tab of the terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, anaconda, conda, environment

It means whenever I open a new tab of terminal, no need to reactivate my environment again. Is there any command to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your shell config to activate your env automatically. In bash for example you can do that via `~/.bashrc`. Conda even asks as the very last step of the installation if a user wants this feature enabled.

Another approach is to use a terminal multiplexer such as `GNU/Screen` or `tmux`, one can activate conda, start `tmux` and have multiple `tmux` windows and all the other cool features.